# Drupal - Use lightbox with Views (Rel attribute) - in output link

Tags: image, drupal, view, lightbox, cck

In Drupal I have two image fields, one to act as a thumbnail and the other the image that will open when the thumbnail is clicked. The only way I could find to link the two was to use the option for "Output this field as a link" and link to the image field.

This works, so when I click the thumbnail it opens the larger image however I would like to use lightbox2 for this task but in the "Output this field as a link" options there is no way to set the "rel" attribute.

Is there a way to either set the rel attribute or invoke the lightbox by setting a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you only need a single cck imagefield to get thumbnail plus full image in lightbox: [Lightbox2 - How to use with CCK Imagefield and Imagecache](http://drupal.org/node/274714).

**UPDATE**: [use the "Lightbox Trigger" Views field](http://drupal.org/node/735424) of the [Lightbox2 development version](http://drupal.org/node/172953). step by step:

- add both your thumbnail and your image field to your view
- mark both of them "Exclude from display". *don't* check "Output this field as a link" anywhere.
- add a "Lightbox trigger" field *after both of your image fields*
- configure the "Lightbox trigger" field:

  - for "Trigger field", select your thumbnail field
  - for "Popup", select the *Replacement pattern* (scroll further down in the view field edit form for all possible replacement pattern) of your image field. for example, in my case, this is `[field_image_fid]`.

now, your view should show your thumbnail image and, clicking on it, should open your full image in a lightbox frame. at least that's what's happening here :)

Comment: I'm looking to allow the user to create a thumbnail that links to a different image